# Make ipython always execute command when I press return key?

Tags: ipython

After migrating to ipython, I noticed that sometimes return key causes a line break instead of executing the command. For example if I have my cursor before `)` in `print()`, it would result in:

`print(
)`

How can I make it just run `print()` in this and other cases?

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you are in multiline mode, e.g.

```
In [200]: for i in range(3):
 ...:     print(i)
 ...:
```

You either need to move to the end of the block (`<end>`) and return twice (or more if editing has accumulated a bunch of blank lines); or use `<esc><return>`.

It shouldn't happen in single line entry.  Wrapped lines maybe.  In any case the `<end>` and `<esc>` work.  The extra key press is the cost of the multiline editing convenience.

Comment: Is there a way to disable multiline completely?

Comment: Re: `<Esc><Return>` -- was looking for this solution everywhere, thanks. This thread/answer is underrated.

Comment: I knew there was a way to do this! thanks @hpaulj