# Change RET behavior in IPython shell

Tags: ipython, config

In IPython (5.3 in this case) pressing the RET has double meaning:

1. send current input to the interpreter
2. insert line break to the current input and let the user to modify it further

Looks like the first one is implemented only if the the cursor is in the beginning or end of the line. How can I change this behavior? For example have a separate keystroke for this purpose.


P.S. Any link to keybindings configuration in IPython would also be much appreciated.

Comment: `<esc><ret>` forces number 1 regardless of where you are in the line, or multiline input, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070453/make-ipython-always-execute-command-when-i-press-return-key

Comment: Thanks for the input, it already helps. I think it is useful to add general solution as an answer to this question i.e. where can I find these key bindings, or even better how can I customize them.